# Alternative to STRING_AGG in with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have a table as below

```
| activityName | UserID | deviceID | createdDate             |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| ON           | 1      | adddsad  |2020-01-09 00:02:59.477  |
| OFF          | 1      | adddsad  |2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | 
| ON           | 2      | bdddsad  |2020-01-09 00:51:11.480  |
| OFF          | 2      | bdddsad  |2020-01-09 00:51:19.450  |
```

when I use `STRING_AGG` like this which is accurate and returns the desired result

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(activityName + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, createdDate), ' | ') AS tag,
       deviceID,
       UserID
FROM (SELECT tag,
             deviceID,
             UserID
      FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster
      WHERE CONVERT(date, createdDate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
      GROUP BY userID) a
GROUP BY UserID;
```

It will return like this

```
| tag                                                           | deviceID  | UserID |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ON - 2020-01-09 00:02:59.477 | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | adddsad   | 1      |
| ON - 2020-01-09 00:51:11.480 | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:51:19.450  | bdddsad   | 2      |
```

On production I have SQL Server 2014 running and had to work on alternative for **`STRING_AGG`** which is not supported on older version

here is alternative I created

```
SELECT deviceID,
       UserID,
       STUFF((SELECT activityName + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar, createdDate)
              FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster
              WHERE userID = tbl_DailyLogMaster.UserID
                AND CONVERT(date, createdDate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
              ORDER BY UserID
             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS tag
FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster
WHERE CONVERT(date, createdDate) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
GROUP BY UserID,
         deviceID,
         UserID,
         createdDate,
         activityName;
```

it returns like this

```
| tag                                                                                                                                | deviceID  | UserID |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| N - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMON - Jan  9 2020 12:02AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:50AM | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | adddsad   | 1      |
| N - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMON - Jan  9 2020 12:02AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:50AM | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | adddsad   | 1      |
| N - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMON - Jan  9 2020 12:02AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:50AM | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | bdddsad   | 2      |
| N - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:51AMON - Jan  9 2020 12:02AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:50AM | OFF - 2020-01-09 00:50:39.857  | bdddsad   | 2      |
```

What I am doing wrong with second query?

Comment: What is tag column in your first query?

Comment: I really suggest starting to use whitespace and line breaks in your SQL. I also seggest you *always* declare your length, scale and precision for your data types. `CONVERT(varchar, {expression})` will cause you problems one day.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is not your SQL Server. Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: @MerHardik Your first code has a more than one error. Please check and correct that.

Comment: @Larnu I have already defined length of data. Its datetime that I am converting into varchar to concatenate two columns.

Comment: *" I have already defined length of data"* No, you don't, @MerHardik : `CONVERT(varchar, createdDate)` Where do you define the length of the `varchar` there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A some what blind guess, but I *think* this is the correct answer. you needed to ensure the subquery was properly correlated:

```
SELECT deviceID,
       UserID,
       STUFF((SELECT ' | ' + sq.activityName + ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar(20),sq.createdDate, 0)
              FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster sq
              WHERE DLM.UserID = sq.UserId
                AND DLM.DeviceID = sq.DeviceID
                AND sq.createdDate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
                AND sq.createdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
              ORDER BY CreatedDate
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(MAX)'),1,3,'') AS tag --As yuou have no leading separator, no need for STUFF
FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster DLM
WHERE DLM.createdDate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND DLM.createdDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY UserID,
         DeviceID;
```

Comment: I do not think your solution is correct. I believe the OP needs two lines. Alos please fix this line: FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster DLM into FROM tbl_DailyLogMaster DML. Cheers

Comment: It's actually the other aliases that were wrong; force of habit to type DML (Data Manipulation Language), @VBoka . As the the start of the comment, I did say this was a blind guess. :)

Comment: Sorry, was focused on the query :)

Comment: @Larnu ON - Jan  9 2020 12:02AMOFF - Jan  9 2020 12:50AM can we have separator between two records?

Comment: Yes, what separator would you want, @MerHardik ?

Comment: @Larnu Jan 9 2020 12:02AM | OFF - Jan 9 2020 12:50AM something like this

Comment: So `' | '` @MerHardik ? If so, please see the updated version.