# How to concatenate column data in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, sql-server-2016, sqlxml

I have a complicated query which returns this:

```
MyID  col1  col2  col3
1     A:11        
1     A:21
1     A:31  
1                 C:13
1                 C:23
2           B:21  
2           B:22
```

I saved the result set of this query in a temp table `#tt` to make things simpler later on.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
MyID  col1              col2        col3
1     A:11__A:21__A:31              C:13__C:23
2                       B:21__B:22
```

But the final query returns this:

```
MyID  col1                col2          col3
1     A:11__A:21__A:31__  ________      ____C:13__C:23
2     __                  B:21__B:22    __
```

This is the query:

```
select
    MyID,
    col1= stuff((select N'__' + col1 from #tt where MyID = x.MyID for xml path(''), type ).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'' ),
    col2= stuff((select N'__' + col2 from #tt where MyID = x.MyID for xml path(''), type ).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'' ),
    col2= stuff((select N'__' + col3 from #tt where MyID = x.MyID for xml path(''), type ).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'' )
from #tt as x
group by MyID
```

As you can see, there are a lot of underscores being returned. Since I am showing a smaller sample of the data, there will be more unneeded underscores when I ran on entire table. It does appear that I am doing some tiny mistake which I cannot figure out. How can I fix the issue?

*If I was using SQL Server 2017 or later, `string_agg()` might have helped a lot.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to STRING\_AGG in with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660493/alternative-to-string-agg-in-with-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the empty or `NULL` values in your subqueries.

```
... from #tt where MyID = x.MyID AND col1 IS NOT NULL AND col1 <> '' ...
```

(And analog for `col2` and `col3`.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this where you're trying to get to?

```
SELECT
    MyID,
    col1 = ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT N'__' + NULLIF(col1, '') FROM #tt WHERE MyID = x.MyID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''), ''),
    col2 = ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT N'__' + NULLIF(col2, '') FROM #tt WHERE MyID = x.MyID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''), ''),
    col2 = ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT N'__' + NULLIF(col3, '') FROM #tt WHERE MyID = x.MyID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''), '')
FROM
    #tt x
GROUP BY
    MyID;
```